# How do I create a pop-up window inside the XLSForm?

Tags: webforms, odk, odk-xform, xlsform

I have a multiple-select question and I need to show a pop-up window to the form user whenever he/she selects one option, in this pop-up window he will answer more questions and close the pop-up to select another item from the multiple-select question or continue the other form questions.

for example, if I have the following multiple-select question:
select one or more items:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

if the user selects an item for (example item 1) a pop window will appear to ask the user to answer a single select question about the gender like the following:
select gender:

- male
- female

after selecting the gender the user could close the pop-up window and if the user selects another item another pop-up window will appear to ask about the gender and so on.

I wonder if there is a workaround to create it in XLSform or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible in XLSForm.

You could automatically create repeats for follow-up questions after answering all multi-select questions (and each repeat could refer to a single multi-select option), but it will get messed if the users goes back to the multi-select afterwards and changes the selected options. I'm not sure if there is a clever way to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Is there a way to hide the repeat questions after answering them without using the collapse functionality? for example can we add a button that the user could use to hide the repeat questions after answering them?

Comment: No, there isn't. Best you could do to approximate this is to give the repeat a `field-list` appearance so each repeat gets its own page (in Enketo, you'd need to add `pages` to the settings column. https://xlsform.org/en/#multiple-webpage-forms